# How to create a custom field from a external plugin in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom field group called playlist in that
I have a custom field called playlist

The field type is checkbox
In that field I have choices like:

```
Evergreen List : Evergreen List
Jazz Music : Jazz Music
Pop Songs : Pop Songs
```

What I need is **through an external plugin** I want to insert or edit a new field like

```
Rock songs : Rock songs
```

Is there any possibility for creating a field like this?

Comment: If you're working with ACF, there should be an option to add new. Otherwise you could edit the field group and add the option.

Comment: Please check "https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-field-suite/" Plugin.

Comment: @PPL I don't want to replace custom fields plugin, I want an external one to create fields for it.